# Applying a function over a Dictionary's value collection

Tags: c#, .net

```
foreach (string key in dbFields.Keys)
     dbFields[key] = MySqlHelper.EscapeString(dbFields[key]);
```

I get an InvalidOperationException error claiming the collection has been modified. **Why does it think the Keys collection has been modified?**

I just want to apply the function to all of the values of the dictionary -_-

I know I can do this if I use a second dictionary. I was just wondering if there is a tight simplistic elegant way to modify all values in a dictionary (without explicitly creating a second one).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (string key in dbFields.Keys.ToList())
     dbFields[key] = MySqlHelper.EscapeString(dbFields[key]);
```

You cannot modify the collection you are iterating over, `ToList()` in this case will create a new `List<string>` for you that you are iterating over, so you can safely modify the dictionary.

In regards to the comment - from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fcwy8h6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> The Dictionary.KeyCollection is not a static
>   copy; instead, the Dictionary.KeyCollection refers back to
>   the keys in the original
>   Dictionary. Therefore,
>   changes to the Dictionary continue to be reflected in
>   the Dictionary.KeyCollection.

So it depends on the implementation of the indexer (`dbFields[key] = ...`) if the Dictionary considers the key collection changed (obviously it does since there's an exception) - unfortunately I don't have Reflector handy at the moment otherwise I could just check.

Comment: What confuses me though - Isn't the Keys collection different collection from the values collection?

Comment: When can change the Keys collection by assigning a value using dbFields[newkey]. therefor you get an exception when doing such an assignment.

Comment: @Volkmar - technically it's not a new key though, it's changing the value for an existing key.

Comment: Setting via the indexer calls into `set_Item`, which calls into `Insert`, which is where I get lost in the IL. I don't have Reflector on my machine, either.